# Genus of a smooth projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I was trying to prove that the genus $g(X)$ of a smooth projective complex plane curve $X=\{[x:y:z]\in \mathbb{P}^2 \vert F(x,y,z)=0\}$ of degree $d$ is equal to $$g(X)=\dfrac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}.$$

My attempt was to take the standard projection $$\pi:\mathbb{P}^2 \to \mathbb{P}^1$$ $$[x :y : z] \to [x : z]$$ which has degree $d$ and then apply Riemann Hurwitz formula.

The problem is that I do not know how to explicitly write the multiplictity of this map at the ramification points(which are the ones for which $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0$). In particular, I would like to say that the multiplicity of the map $\pi $ in a point $x \in \mathbb{P}^2$ is $I\left(x,F \cap \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}+1\right)$, but I'm stuck (the last I is the intersection multiplicity of the two algebraic curves).

Comment: Are you asking about how to finish this particular proof using the Riemann-Hurwitz formula, or are you interested in alternate ways to prove this statement?

Comment: I would like to see a proof using Riemann Hurwitz formula

Comment: Is it okay to use adjunction + cohomology ?  Then $K_C = \mathcal{O}_C(n-3) $. Since the curve is defined by a single equation of degree d it's easy to see that $K_C$ has exactly the same global sections as on $P^2$.

Comment: I think this is basically a duplicated of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1918738/genus-of-a-curve-silvermans-book).

Comment: @André3000 Tthe answer in there is just a **broken** link, it might be worth it having a written answer.

Answer (score 3):

One proof of this variant of the genus-degree formula (aka "Plücker's formula") is given on page 144 of Miranda's *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*. Supposedly, another more geometric proof is sketched [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45434/proving-that-the-genus-of-a-nonsingular-plane-curve-is-fracd-1d-22).

Let me finish your proof with the help of Miranda. As you note, the proper non-constant holomorphic mapping $$\pi\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$$ $$[x:y: z]\mapsto [x:z]$$ has degree $d$, where $d$ is the degree of the homogeneous polynomial $F$. Thus, to calculate the topological genus of the compact Riemann surface $X$ (with the help of the Riemann-Hurwitz formula) all that is left to do is to find the non-negative integer $\sum_{p\in X}\big(\operatorname{mult}_p(\pi)-1\big)$. Here, $\operatorname{mult}_p(\pi)$ denotes the multiplicity of $\pi$ at $p\in X$.

---

To do so, we employ the notion of a [divisor on a Riemann surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_(algebraic_geometry)#Divisors_on_a_Riemann_surface). Namely, we use the following two examples of divisors on $X$. Firstly, we introduce a divisor whose degree is precisely the non-negative integer $\sum_{p\in X}\big(\operatorname{mult}_p(\pi)-1\big)$ which we wish to calculate.

> **Definition.** The *ramification divisor* of the non-constant holomorphic mapping $\pi\colon X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ is the divisor on $X$ defined by
> $$R_\pi =\sum_{p\in X}\big(\operatorname{mult}_p(\pi)-1\big)\cdot p.$$

Secondly, we introduce a divisor on $X$ which will help us calculate the degree of the ramification divisor $R_\pi$.

> **Definition.** Let $G$ a homogeneous polynomial that is not identically zero on $X$. Let $p\in X$. If $G(p)=0$, then find a homogeneous polynomial $H$ of the same degree as $G$ that does not vanish at $p$. In this case, let the integer $\operatorname{div}(G)(p)$ be the order of the meromorphic function $G/H$ at $p$. If $G(p)\neq 0$, then we set $\operatorname{div}(G)(p)=0$. One shows that the integer $\operatorname{div}(G)(p)$ is well-defined (i.e., independent of the choice of $H$) and calls the divisor $\operatorname{div}(G)\colon X \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ the *intersection divisor* of $G$ on $X$.

Next, we recall the following two results. Proofs can be found in Miranda's book. The first theorem gives a formula to calculate the degree of any intersection divisor on $X$.

> **Bezout's theorem** (essentially Theorem 2.13 in Miranda's book). Let $G$ be a homogeneous polynomial which is not identically zero on $X$. Then the degree of the intersection divisor $\operatorname{div}(G)$ of $G$ on $X$ is equal to the product of the degrees of $G$ and $X$: $$\operatorname{deg}(\operatorname{div}(G))=\operatorname{deg}(G)\operatorname{deg}(X).$$

The second lemma states that the ramification divisor $R_\pi$ is equal to the intersection divisor of a certain homogeneous polynomial obtained by partial differentiation of $F$.

> **Lemma** (Lemma 2.14 in Miranda's book). The polynomial $\partial F /\partial y$ is homogeneous of degree $d-1$ and the intersection divisor of $\partial F /\partial y$ of $X$ is equal to the ramification divisor $R_\pi$ of $\pi$ on $X$.

---

We now have all the necessary ingredients to prove Plücker's formula. Namely, Bezout's theorem and the above lemma yield $$\sum_{p\in X}(\operatorname{mult}_p(\pi)-1)=d(d-1).$$ With the Riemann-Hurwitz formula, we thus have $$2g(X)-2=-2d+d(d-1).$$ Solving for $g(X)$ shows the claim $$g(X)=\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}={d-1\choose 2}.$$

Comment: I'm struggling to show the degree of the map $\pi$ given in the original post is $d$.  Could you please sketch the argument for me?

Comment: @Derek This is explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3643960/pluckers-formula-proof), for instance. To understand the post you need to know that the ramification points of $\pi$ are precisely the zeroes of $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$. This is explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511153/condition-for-ramification-points-of-a-projection-pi-x-to-mathbbp1).